# check box value Showing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkbox and disabled textbox. When checkbox is true, text box will be active and focused. when false, it become disabled. i added blur event on the text box and check box change event for certain operations.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest1" name="chkTest1" value="Bike"> check</br>
<input type="text" id="txtTest1" disabled  />
```

Script

```
$('#chkTest1').change(function() {

var flagCheck = $(this).prop('checked');
$('#txtTest1').prop('disabled', !flagCheck).val('').off();
if(flagCheck)
{
  $('#txtTest1').focus();  
}    

$('#txtTest1').blur(function () {                
    console.log($("#chkTest1").prop('checked'));                
   });
});
```

My problem is

when checkbox makes false, text box disabled and lost focus. so checkbox change event and blur event will be fired. But in blur event, check box value still be true instead of false. How to resolve this.

Here the Code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glitson/ka1mkfrv/3/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: value still be true...Means?

Comment: when check box makes false, blur event fired. If we print check box value in the event, true will be return. actually the value is false at the time.

Comment: Use on click an `$(this).is(':checked');` or `this.checked` - change triggers on blur as you have noticed

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox is clicked directly after filling the field then you need to wait since the blur triggers before the click that changes the checkbox.
Also be aware that the `.off()` will remove the blur handler from the text field after clicking!

```js
$(function() {
  $('#chkTest1').on("click", function() {
    var flagCheck = this.checked;
    $('#txtTest1').prop('disabled', !flagCheck).val('');
    if (flagCheck) {
      $('#txtTest1').focus();
    }
  });

  $("#txtTest1").on("blur", function() {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("test check",$("#chkTest1").is(':checked')); },500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest1" name="chkTest1" value="Bike">check</br>
<input type="text" id="txtTest1" disabled />
```

Comment: can't we resoleve other than delaying  the function.

Comment: What is the actual reason for testing in the blur?

Comment: this is used for tab operation. when click tab on the text box this functional code will be worked. accidenty this is also worked when check box become false. Main purpose of me is to avoid blur functionality when checkbox become false.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Glitson George:

     i explaned why i am removing
 the blur event in the below fiddle. Please check jsfiddle.net/ka1mkfrv/6 .
    once blur function stored in memory,
 2nd time onwards  blur function will excute first  then change event will excute

 Please check the console for this.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka1mkfrv/6/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to keep the text box content when disabling the checkbox:

```
$('#chkTest1').change(function() {
  var flagCheck = $(this).prop('checked');

  if(flagCheck)
  {
    $('#txtTest1').prop('disabled', !flagCheck).val('').off();
    $('#txtTest1').focus();  
  } else {
    $('#txtTest1').prop('disabled', !flagCheck);
  }    
  $('#txtTest1').blur(function () {                
    console.log($("#chkTest1").prop('checked'));                
  });  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka1mkfrv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your below code will only be executed when textbox is not *disabled*

```
$('#txtTest1').blur(function () {                
    console.log($("#chkTest1").prop('checked'));                
});
```

So when your textbox will be enabled at the same time your checkbox will also be enabled.

When your text-box will be disabled at the same time checkbox  your checkbox will also be disabled but your above will not be not execute.

That's why you cannot print the false value of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

below is the working fiddle

```
$(document).on("change",'#chkTest1',function() {
 var flagCheck = $(this).is(':checked')
  if(flagCheck){
    $('#txtTest1').removeAttr('disabled').val('').off();
     $('#txtTest1').focus();  
    }
    else
    {
    $('#txtTest1').prop('disabled', !flagCheck).val('');
    console.log($("#chkTest1").is(':checked')); 
   }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka1mkfrv/5/

Comment: why did u remove blur functionality.

Comment: No. Links can go stale. Please copy your code here.

Comment: How do you know what he needs? He wants to use the blur. We can ask him, but not just remove it

Comment: @krishna why do you insist that people have to leave SO to see your code in action? I fixed it for you and you removed the snippet

Comment: @mplungjan:  i am just removing the extra event. i am optimizing the code

Comment: I made a snippet. It ran here. You have removed the snippet so now we AGAIN must go to jsfiddle to see your code running! Also you do not know what is in the blur event in his full code.

Comment: @Glitson George: i explaned why i am removing the blur event in the below fiddle. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/ka1mkfrv/6/ .  once blur function stored in memory 2nd time onwards  first blur function will  excute then change event will excute.